# Why does the multiplication implementation for Complex require a RealFloat?

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers

In GHCi, one finds the following:

```
 import Data.Complex
 :t 2 * (3 :+ 4)
2 * (3 :+ 4) :: RealFloat a => Complex a
 :t (* (3 :+ 4))
(* (3 :+ 4)) :: RealFloat a -> Complex a -> Complex a
```

However:

```
 :t fmap (* 2) (3 :+ 4)
fmap (* 2) (3 :+ 4) :: Num a => Complex a -> Complex a
```

Now, why is this so? Is it just that `fromInteger` under `Num a => Complex a` has type `RealFloat a => a -> Complex a`? If so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Complex a` only instantiates `Num` if `a` instantiates `RealFloat`. That is the `Num` instance is defined as:

```
instance RealFloat a => Num (Complex a) where
    ...
```

Since `*` is defined by `Num`, you can only use `*` on a `Complex a` if it's an instance of `Num`, i.e. if `a` is an instance of `RealFloat`.

So why does the `Num` instance have that restriction?

It's because of this method:

```
abs :: a -> a
```

The absolute value of a complex number can be non-integral even if both its components are integers. For example the absolute value of 1+1i is √2. So a method `abs :: Complex Integer -> Complex Integer` can't be defined (at least not in a way that produces correct results), therefore no complete instance of `Num (Complex Integer)` can be defined. So there's only one for `RealFloat`s.

The same is true for the `signum` method.

Comment: ... an example of why `Num` is a bit of a mixed-up class :)

Comment: The reason for RealFloat rather than Floating is actually more subtle. :)  It’s (/) that is the culprit.

Comment: @augustss you should make that an answer.